# Laravel constraining eager loading not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am making a query where I would like to check the relationship that I have set up like this:

Content model:

```
public function contentType()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\ContentType', 'ct_id');
}
```

ContentType

```
public function contents()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Content', 'ct_id');
}
```

And, then I have tried to do a query like this:

```
$content = Content::where('slug', $arguments['slug'])
                ->with(['contentType' => function ($query) {
                    $query->where('slug', 'post');
                }])->get();

return $content;
```

Where I wanted to get `$content` from the Db, that has the `contentType` of slug `post`, and I am getting the content from the table, but after testing it, I am getting the same record every time no matter what I put as a `slug` for `contentType`. I only have one record in the Db, that is why I am getting the same record, but I should even get that one, if it doesn't have the `contentType` that has a `slug` different than `post`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand your question entirely, you're retrieving a record from the table content and this has a record associated in the contentType table. You're always obtaining the same record of the contentType?

Comment: I am always obtaining the same record from the content table, no matter what I put as ContentType

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve what I want with `whereHas` query:

```
$content = Content::whereHas('contentType', function ($query) {
                    $query->whereIn('slug', ['post', 'page']);
                })
                ->where('slug', $arguments['slug'])
                ->with('supplementary')
                ->first();
```

That way I fetch only content that has either post or page as a slug in the  `contentType` relationship.